# Spring security:How to map j_spring_security_check in controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm trying to integrate spring security into existing code base which is in spring mvc.

In my existing code base i v'e a client delegate in web project which interacts with service delegate in service project which in turn interacts with service interface of back-end layer.It is the service interface impl of back-end layer which i'm making implement the UserDetailsService interface.

P.S - I'm creating/converting/passing on various objects i.e. Model,DO,DTO,Request,Response etc across all the layers.

So now,when i click on submit i want the control to go through the delegate from web to back-end layer till the class which implements UserDetailsService interface. How can i achieve this?

[Update]:After going through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971453/spring-security-custom-filter) i changed my security xml like shown below:

```
     <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/portalLogin.html" login-processing-url="/signIn" always-use-default-target="true"
    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/welcome.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />
</security:http>
```

My LoginController is like this:

```
      @RequestMapping("/signIn")
        public ModelAndView onClickLogin(@ModelAttribute("dashboard")
        LoginModel loginModel,Model model){
        try{
        delegate.clickLogin(loginModel);
        if(null != loginModel.getError()){
            // return new ModelAndView("error");
        }       
        }catch(Exception exception){
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:welcome.html");

        }
```

[Update]:Sorry for very late update.Controller Mapping issue is resolved, now i'm facing issues because of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.After comparing logs generated by above code with properly working code logs,i figured out that spring security is not firing 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' for some reasons in my case.'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' is the one which authenticates the user.

```
            //Logs when authentication is done 
            [while using spring's default /j_spring_security_check].

    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
    DEBUG UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
    DEBUG ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    session created
    DEBUG SessionImpl - Opened session at timestamp: 13661947944
    SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])
    After openSession
    DEBUG SessionImpl - Opened session at timestamp: 13661947944
    Criteria before eq::this::CriteriaImpl(com.infy.itrade.core.entity.LoginDO:this[][])::CriteriaImpl(com.infy.itrade.core.entity.LoginDO:this[][])...

    //Logs when authentication is not done [while using custom login processing url : /signIn.html].
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' //UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not doing authentication process instead it skips to next filter.
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
```

I created a custom filter 'MyFilter' which extends 'AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter'. But still 'MyFilter' doesn't do any authentication as the log shows the following:

```
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MyFilter'
    DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /signIn.html at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
```

MyFilter:

```
    public class MyFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final String DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URL = "/signIn";
    private static final String POST = "POST";
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "username";
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";
    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY = "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME";

    private String usernameParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY;
    private String passwordParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY;

    public MyFilter() {
        super(DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URL);
    }

    public MyFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username, password);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null || getAllowSessionCreation()) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY,
                    TextEscapeUtils.escapeEntities(username));
        }
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        if (request.getMethod().equals(POST)) {
            // If the incoming request is a POST, then we send it up
            // to the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.
            super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
        } else {
            // If it's a GET, we ignore this request and send it
            // to the next filter in the chain. In this case, that
            // pretty much means the request will hit the /login
            // controller which will process the request to show the
            // login page.
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
    ...
    }
```

Context xml:

```
    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/portalLogin.html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="MyFilter" class="com.infosys.itrade.core.dao.security.MyFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"></property>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"></property>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/signIn"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome.html" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/loginfailed.html" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="LoginUserDetailsService">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="LoginUserDetailsService"
        class="com.infy.itrade.core.service.login.LoginServiceImpl">
        <property name="logindao" ref="loginDAOImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginDAOImpl" class="com.infy.itrade.core.dao.login.LoginDAODBImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory"> <ref bean ="sessionFactory"/> </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What am i missing here?

[Update]: Since i couldn't get this working i changed my approach as suggested by others here i.e. I'm avoiding the architectural flow for login module alone. But right now i'm facing a different issue with the new approach for which i'll ask a different question. Thanks.

Comment: @MaksymDemidas : I've configured UserDetailsService in security xml as i've created the bean for service interface impl of back-end layer which implements UserDetailsService interface.Regarding filter, i'm using default filter provided by spring security i.e. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which in turn looks up for j_spring_security_check. Do i need to go for custom authentication filter?

Comment: I do not view any reason. Can you respond to my first question?

Comment: @MaksymDemidas : I'm working on preexisting code base which is divided into three different projects i.e.web,service & core projects.The reason behind this is to make the code across different layers loosely coupled from each other.Also, there will be different clients i.e. web app,mobile etc hence the methods in the service projects are exposed as web services.So i'm just trying to integrate spring security in this flow.

Comment: Ok. May be there is something in existing code that forces you to have a custom controller mapper to /j_spring_security_check. What I am trying to say is that it is not necessary at all. Live UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to do his work (remove your /j_spring_security_check controller ). Configure default authentication manager, default authentication provider and link your custom UserDatailsService to authentication provider in security xml. If you need to call some existed code during auth. process then use auth. success handler and auth. failure handler (form-login attributes).

Comment: When i make the service class in core project as implementor of UserDetailsService interface directly without going through web,service layers and reference the same in security context, everything works fine.I'm stuck at the point when user submits the login page,as per existing code form action is mapped to controller for login processing.But when it comes to spring security,form action is /j_spring_security_check and i've to map this in controller so that i go on till the back-end layer populating all Model,Entity,DTO's.DTO will be used by other clients through web services.

Comment: If you want to use your custom controller for authentication processing then you can choose any URL for it. You do not need to use /j_spring_security_check.

Comment: i fyou are using a custom controller, it kinda removes the poitn of using spring secruity, imho.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - I'm working on preexisting code base which is divided into three different projects i.e.web,service & core projects.The reason behind this is to make the code across different layers loosely coupled from each other.Model,DO,DTO,Request,Response objects etc are transferred across all the layers.Also, there will be different clients i.e. web app,mobile etc hence the methods in the service projects are exposed as web services.So i'm just trying to integrate spring security in this flow.So are you saying it's not good to integrate security to this architecture?

Comment: @coder87 it sounds quite complex, it may be your best option.

Comment: @NimChimpsky- ok,now i got my own controller working after getting config right and i've made sure that control is going till DAO layer. Right now I'm stuck because UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not doing authentication in my case as i've explained above with logs i got.I've compared correctly working logs with mine.Any idea what i need to resolve this?